# Flutter/Dart + gRPC Stream error: Stream was terminated by peer (errorCode: 2)

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc

I'm having this intermittent error come up when making a call from a Dart gRPC client to a Go gRPC server. The exact error message is:

> gRPC Error (code: 2, codeName: UNKNOWN, message: HTTP/2 error: Stream
> error: Stream was terminated by peer (errorCode: 2)

This seems to occur frequently on creating the client stub with the channel and making a call to the server. Subsequent calls seems to work fine with a response returned correctly to the client. Then this error intermittently pops up again every n-th call (could be after 5 calls, 10 calls sometimes no errors until the 20th call).

When I use a different client (eg: BloomRPC or Java app I wrote), this does not happen no matter how hard or fast I spam the calls to the server. This kind of implies the server is probably not the issue.

Can anyone shine a light on what might be happening? Or provide some hints as to where to start looking/debugging? I've tried stepping through the code, but not really able to follow what is happening when the gRPC call is made/returned.

Steps in the client code:

create ClientChannel with ip, ports

```
final cc = ClientChannel(serverIP,
port: serverPort,
options:
const ChannelOptions(credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure()
));
```

created a stub based on above channel

```
_userQueryStub = UserQueryGRPCClient(cc,
options: CallOptions(timeout: Duration(seconds: 30)));
```

call function from stub (repeatedly)

```
GetUserInformationRequest request = GetUserInformationRequest(userId: userId);
GetUserInformationResponse response = await _userQueryStub.getUserInformation(request);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!